# JPG image renders as code

Tags: html, image, browser-cache

My image thumbnail links to the full size image. Now only the image is showing up as some sort of code. I have been using the same HTML editor for years, all the pages are the same. It is only this group of 5 pages that have thumbnails. Take this link for example:

```
ÿØÿáExifII*ÿìDucky2ÿáyhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ ÿíHPhotoshop 3.08BIMZ%G8BIM%üá‰È·Éx/4b4XwëÿîAdobedÀÿÛ
```

I also discovered that if I get this code an then go up to the history and click on the name of the photo it pops right up as it should have been. I have no idea how to fix this. I have uploaded the photos several times with two file managers, used other photo software aswell. My editor shows that these pages are fine, but IE shows that the pages have no style and all browsers show the linked image problem.
I know this doesn't make much sense to you professionals, but this is my business website and a customer told me about the problem. After 8 hours of trying to fix this I am hoping you could help.

Comment: Can you show us some code where the image is being displayed? Or maybe you can share the link to the site so we can see the issue in action.

Comment: I have been trying to solve the issue with the CSS not showing up on this same group of pages. 
Here is a link to one page and if you click on the thumbnail you can see that I have code instead of the large photo. Also then click on the page in history and the photo loads.

http://adams-harris.com/dolls/fashion_dolls/13_inches_below/girl_dolls/paola_reina/back_to_school/back_to_school.html

Comment: You may want to include this in your question . [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

> **The problem:**

This problem occurs when an IMG changes or got touched (by adobe, in your case) *AFTER* it was uploaded to the server and the name of the new (or modified) IMG remained the same. The image shown does not get refreshed. The old image is still shown, even though the database holds the right image. I have narrowed it down to the fact that the **IMAGE IS CACHED** in the web browser. If we hit the *RELOAD* button in *Firefox/Explorer/Safari*, everything gets refreshed fine and the correct image just appears.

I verified that on your site running the following:

```
function is_cached(img_url){
    var imgEle = document.createElement("img");
    imgEle.src = img_url;
    return imgEle.complete || (imgEle.width+imgEle.height) > 0;
}
```

And then I called this function which returns true or false depending on cached or not:

```
is_cached("photos/back_to_school_pr5_tn.jpg");
```

And the result came back as:

```
<- true
```

**Remember**: When uploading an image, its filename is not kept in the database. It is renamed as Image.jpg (to simply things out when using it). When replacing the existing image with a new one, the name doesn't change either. Just the content of the image file changes.

> **Solution one** - No code required:

Since you are not in the coding business (as you claim), all you need to do is to *rename* the IMG after it's been touched by adobe. 
Whenever you modify a photo in adobe or you upload a new IMG you should give it a new name since the older version of the IMG **IS STILL IN CACHE.**

> **Solution two** - Coding required:

If touching the IMG with adobe is a constant thing that you do after you upload the original picture, then the above solution can be an hassle, so you might want to look into ways to force the web browser to NOT cache images from this page.

**NOTE:** This solution is only good for the future. In your case, the IMG is already cached. 
Besides, this will only work if the actual IMG is **inside your HTML**, but on your site the link takes you to the actual IMG.

> **Solution three** - Coding required:

An important addition to the above solution is that you can never force a browser to do anything. All you can do is make friendly suggestions. It's up to the browser and the user to actually follow those suggestions. A browser is free to ignore this, or a user could override the defaults. 
So the best *long-term* solution will be to save the filename with the database. This way, if the image is changed, the src of the IMG tag will also change. 
For example:

```
<img src="picture.jpg?1222259157.415" alt="">
```

where "1222259157.415" is the current time on the server. (Note: I used python's `time.time()` to generate that)

Comment: I appreciate your help but to be honest I have tried it and I don't understand how to make this work on my page. I am not a web designer as you can tell.
I would really like to know what that code is and where it came from. All of the photos on my site are shot with the same camera, edited in Photo Shop and the web pages are written in Webuilder. I used working existing pages as the templates for these pages. I have compared working and nonworking pages side by side. I thought for sure it would be a quote out of place. I just can't see the problem.

Comment: I added a not-coding-required solution. I've spend quite some time figuring this out. I hope that's the case by you and just renaming the pic would do.

Comment: I have deleted all the files. I have renamed all the indexes, pages, photos and thumbnails and uploaded the new files to my site and nothing changed.
I'm still not sure where to get the Python. I see you put the code in <img src= the photo an then I guess that is the time stamp.  Would this go on each photo, or could I put it in the header once instead? My CSS is still missing from all the pages. Same CSS is used on working pages.
Example of index, click any thumb to take you back to new nonworking pages and photos.
http://adams-harris.com/pattern_indexs/paola_index.html

Comment: Before I look into it further, can you change the IMG link to open on a new tab? Let's see if that will help.  It's anyways a good idea for to do that. You don't want your users to leave the main site. The proper way though would be to have some JS to change the bigger thumbnail with the one clicked.

Comment: They all open in a new window the same as in the old. I also tried using a different picture that works on another page, I got the same results , the thumb showed up but the photo was gibberish. 
I don't know if it is the pictures messing with the pages or the pages messing with the pictures. Side by side with a page from another doll in the same "under 13" folder I can't see a difference in code.

Comment: No, the page you provided does not open the IMG in a new tab. To do this, add the `target_blank` attribute to the `<a>` element.  For example: `<a href = "your_IMG.jpg" target = "_blank">`

Comment: If the renaming process didn't help, The problem you are facing is caused (most probably) by a line of your httpd.conf. I will update my answer for a solution for this after I can confirm that this is indeed your problem.

Comment: I just used one of the nonworking photos on a facebook post and it shows up fine. I tried to virus scan the files and they seem okay. I talked to my host and they checked for a virus or anything odd but nada.

Comment: First let's see how it'll function after you add  the target _blank. Will take it from there.

Comment: I added target = blank to the apple pie page for the first photo. I hope that is what you meant.  Like this
<a href="photos/apple1.jpg" target = "_blank"><img src="photos/apple1_tn.jpg" width="45" height="60" alt="Apple Pie pattern on Paola Reina"></a>
right click>new window= same gibberish
click link also = same gibberish

Comment: Pls share link.

Comment: http://adams-harris.com/dolls/fashion_dolls/13_inches_below/girl_dolls/paola/apple_paola/apple_paola.html.html     First photo

Comment: Actually, when opening in new tab, it shows up correctly on my phone (Safari).  While I'm investing further, you can place the IMG in its separate HTML and link to that page. That should be the temporarily fix.

Comment: One more thing to try, add to your IMG link a random number like your_image?123455. Let's see results.

Comment: http://adams-harris.com/dolls/fashion_dolls/13_inches_below/girl_dolls/paola/apple_paola/apple_paola.html.html     That worked! I didn't try the number yet and I still have the no CSS problem but at least this is an improvement. I will give the number a try tomorrow, I have to get to work.

Comment: I just tested the numbers on the second thumbnail on the page and it didn't change the problem. I am trying to solve the no CSS on the index page now. I will write it again but want to test it by deleting the thumbs one at a time because I know it has worked again when one of the thumbs was missing.

Comment: I have tested pages and this is it so far
.png is the same as .jpg on all pages

Comment: Firefox has CSS on index and pages now but no picture

Comment: Chrome is the same as Firefox and IE has no CSS on pages but picture displays correctly.

Comment: So Moses, if you are still around, everything is working as far as I can tell on IE the only thing still not working is Chrome and FF on those images. If you have given up, I understand.

Comment: We never give up, we're always around.

Comment: So don't ask me how, but I finally got one page working so used it as a template not that I can see any difference in them side by side. I used the new working page as a template and now everything it working. I would love to know what that page of gibberish was all about. FF had a page on it but then linked the question about photos back to the link about pages which didn't apply. Again I do thank you for all your help. It is nice to know there are people willing to help.

Comment: That's great to hear!